# ValueError uses no argument in pytest, does order of decorators matter?

Tags: python, pytest

I ran into a very cryptic error in pytest, after adding a '@pytest.mark.parametrize' decorator the test started throwing the following error:

```
ValueError: <function ... at ...> uses no argument 'parameters'
```

I found the source of the error [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/ef1b91ba8721e85430eead4c2849d8e072fe8350/src/_pytest/python.py#L893)

Here's what the signature of my function looks like (simplified):

```
@patch('dog')
@pytest.mark.parametrize('foo,bar', test_data)
def test_update_activity_details_trainer_and_gear(self, foo, bar, dog):
```

Comment: this is probably useful reading for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators/1594484#1594484

Answer (score 25):

Turns out the order of decorators in pytest matters

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('foo,bar', test_data)
@patch('dog')
def test_update_activity_details_trainer_and_gear(self, dog, foo, bar):
```

Changing the order removed the error

Comment: Of course. Decorators are just a syntactic sugar. Just like `a(b(c()))` may not be the same as `c(b(a()))`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message for a similar use case.
The error occured because I omitted to put `mock` as the first keyword argument in my testing function.

This works:

```
import unittest.mock as mock

@pytest.mark.parametrize('foo,bar', test_data)
@mock.patch('module.dog.Dog.__init__', return_value=None)
def test_update_activity_details_trainer_and_gear(_: mock.MagicMock, foo, bar):
```

This errors out with: `In test_update_activity_details_trainer_and_gear: function uses no argument 'foo'`

```
import unittest.mock as mock

@pytest.mark.parametrize('foo,bar', test_data)
@mock.patch('module.dog.Dog.__init__', return_value=None)
def test_update_activity_details_trainer_and_gear(foo, bar):
```